# vue component destroys before transition finishes

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify `<v-fade-transition>` to do a transition when the view changed. But some components destroy before the out transition finishes.

This is my transition looks like.

```
<v-content>
    <v-fade-transition mode="out-in">
        <router-view/>
    </v-fade-transition>
    <dashboard-content-footer/>
</v-content>
```

And this is one of my views

```
<v-container>
    <v-btn color="primary">new</v-btn>
    <v-btn>print</v-btn>
    <v-row align="center">
        <v-label class="text-center">date</v-label>
        <v-col cols="2">
            <DateInput icon="mdi-home" label="From"></DateInput>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="2">
            <DateInput icon="mdi-home" label="To"></DateInput>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <Table
            :headers="headers"
            url="localhost:8000/get"
    ></Table>
</v-container>
```

The problem is that the `<DateInput>` destroyed before the out transition finished while the other components just destroyed after the transition completed as expected.

And this is my DateInput

```
<v-menu
        v-model="menu"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        transition="slide-y-transition"
        offset-y
        max-width="290px"
        min-width="290px"
>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-text-field
                v-model="computedDateFormatted"
                :label="label"
                persistent-hint
                :prepend-icon="icon"
                readonly
                outlined
                v-on="on"
                :dense="dense"
        ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker v-model="date" no-title @input="menu2 = false"></v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

I wonder if the `DateInput` can destroy just after the transition completed.

Sorry for my unclear presentation and Thanks in advance :D